# React firebase wait to then finish

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

Hello I use firestorage to save a image and after I use a if for send the information with the url, but then get url after condition, I know that then is a promise and async but I need that my condition wait then and I don't know how to my condition can wait a then to finish inside a function?

```
 event.preventDefault();
let file = enterFileImage.imageFile;
imageUploader(file);

if (enterPhone.imageUrl != null) {
  const db = firebase.firestore();
  const docRef = db
    .collection("phones")
    .add({
      ...enterPhone,
    })
    .then((docRef) => {
      console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
    });
}
```

**imageUploader**

```
const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref("/images");
const imageRef = storageRef.child(enterFileImage.imageName);
await imageRef.put(file).then((snapshot) => {
  snapshot.ref
    .getDownloadURL()
    .then((url) => {
      console.log(url)

      setPhone((Prevstate) => ({
        ...Prevstate,
        imageName: enterFileImage.imageName,
        imageUrl: url,
      }));
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
      return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to "bubble up" the result from the inner operations to the outer one. You already do this in your `catch`, but also need to do it in your `then`:

```
await imageRef.put(file).then((snapshot) => {
  return snapshot.ref
    .getDownloadURL()
    .then((url) => {
      console.log(url)

      setPhone((Prevstate) => ({
        ...Prevstate,
        imageName: enterFileImage.imageName,
        imageUrl: url,
      }));
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
      return false;
    });
});
```

By returning the result from `snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL()`, your calling code will wait until the file has been uploaded **and** its download URL has been determined.

Comment: doesn't work I put a console.log() after function to see if save url, but it's same, in the console show first hook and after 1 o 2 seconds show the url I need the opposite order

Comment: Now I put await imageUploader() and work, but the hook state enterPhone is too slow to update and the condition to check url still doesn't work, if I use react tools update, but too slow

Comment: I could resolve, use return all and I put inside a variable

Comment: Good to hear 